# Is it possible to subclass wx.grid.Grid and also use my own metaclass?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, protocols, static-analysis, metaclass

I have an application that displays various grids. The grids have different kinds of functionality, so the design I have is a base grid class that handles generic grid things, and a variety of feature mixins to mix into a class with a base grid:

```py
class BaseGrid(wx.grid.Grid):

    def foo():
        return 0

class Grid_Mixin1():

    def feature():
        self.foo()

class Grid_Mixin2():
    def feature():
        self.foo()

class SpecificGrid(Mixin1, BaseGrid):
    ...
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use type hints, and inside the mixins, the type checker doesn't know that `self.foo()` will exist, raising an unknown member error.

I decided to use protocols to let the static type checker know what the mixins conform to:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class MyProtocol(Protocol):

    def foo(self):
        ...

class Grid_Mixin1(MyProtocol):

    def feature():
        self.foo()

class Grid_Mixin2(MyProtocol):
    def feature():
        self.foo()
```

Now when I try to use `SpecificGrid`, I get the infamous

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must
> be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I can only assume that wx.grid.Grid is deriving from its own metaclass? It's not obvious to me from the documentation, but that's the only explanation I have. Is my assessment correct? What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - they have different metaclasses, and thus you'd have to create a combined metaclass to be able to combine both classes.

That is easier than it sounds - since both wx and typing are well maintained code, and have no inherent conflict in class layout, creating a non-conflicting metaclass is just a matter of combining both metaclasses.

The problem, however, is with typing.Protocol subclasses: this hierarchy is not meant to specify real concrete classes - it is meant to specify an interface describing other classes that may or may not represent it. (That is unlike the classes in `collections.abc` - which describe a 'protocol' and *also* have an implementation of mixin methods)

Which means that when one *does* combine the metaclasses for Protocol and wx.grid.Grid, all one gets is another error:

```py
In [2]: import wx.grid                                                                                                                    

In [3]: wx.grid.Grid.__class__                                                                                                            
Out[3]: sip.wrappertype

In [4]: m1 = wx.grid.Grid.__class__                                                                                                       

In [5]: from typing import Protocol                                                                                                       

In [6]: m2 = Protocol.__class__                                                                                                           

In [7]: class m3(m1, m2): pass                                                                                                            

In [8]: class test(wx.grid.Grid, Protocol): pass                                                                                          
[...]
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

In [9]: class test(wx.grid.Grid, Protocol, metaclass=m3): pass                                                                            
[...]
TypeError: Protocols can only inherit from other protocols, got <class 'wx._grid.Grid'>
```

So, the correct thing to do is not to inherit from Protocol at all - implement your class that have the concrete implementation of your protocol, just as a mixin, and use it normally to compose your Grid class - and have your
Protocol hierarchy just as a set of dummy classes, containing only the methods, attributes and their annotations - this would inherit from `typing.Protocol`

If you don't want to write the declarations of methods and annotations twice, which is understandable, it is possible to declare the concrete classes implementing the protocol, and use some code to be run in the *body* of a class inheriting from `Protocol`. This code can copy the methods (and their annotations) from the other class to your protocol (abstract) class - which then will work with the static checkers and other software that relies on the static annotations:

```py
In [19]: class MyBase: 
    ...:     def foo(self) -> None: pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                                  

In [20]: class MyProtcol(Protocol): 
    ...:     for name in dir(MyBase): 
    ...:         if not name.startswith("__"): 
    ...:             locals()[name] = getattr(PBase, name) 
    ...:              
    ...:                                                                                                                                  

In [21]: MyProtcol._is_protocol                                                                                                           
Out[21]: True
```

Comment: **This approach will *not* will work with static type-checkers** (e.g., mypy, `pyright`). Static type-checkers are *not* run at runtime; they're run *outside* runtime – typically from within an IDE. Static type-checkers only perform static analysis through traditional parsing. They don't actually run anything and thus have no means of deciphering the ad-hoc magically dynamic runtime implementation of your `MyProtocol` subclass. In other words, `typing.Protocol` is largely useless for most real-world purposes.

Comment: _nothing_ involving metaclasses will work with static type checkers. One have to keep in mind it is an optional and auxiliar thing to Python.